# Multiple Interrupt Levels Purpose

Tags: assembly, interrupt, cpu-architecture, interrupt-handling, low-level

Wondering why multiple interrupt levels are needed...does it prevent memory corruption, allow the ability to run real time systems??

Does it allow to run high priority interrupts during low priority interrupts?

Comment: The second one. Allows higher priority interrupts while low priority ones are serviced, or at least if multiple interrupts are pending then they are serviced starting with the highest priority one. Exact details depend on your architecture and how the handlers are coded.

Comment: Some devices are very high speed while others not.  The lower speed devices can tolerate interrupts by higher speed devices; user code is just the lowest priority.

Comment: allows developers to decide what they feel are the higher priority and lower priority interrupts

Comment: As commented, it allows higher priority interrupts to interrupt lower priority interrupts, You could think of this as a hardware variation of a preemptive multi-threaded environment.